# What is that component from the ADP5091 Schematic?

Tags: voltage-regulator, components, charge-pump

[image: The component in the yellow circle]

I am looking for an explanation what that component does inside of that circuit. 
It can be found on page 3 of the Datasheet of ADP5091:
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADP5091-5092.pdf

It would help me out a lot. Thank you in advance!

Comment: A current measurement, maybe?

Comment: Thats the most likely answer - on page 20 of the data sheet a current limiting for the low-side switch is described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the block diagram and page 16

> The switching mode synchronous **boost regulator**, with an external
>   **inductor connected between the VIN and the SW pins**, operates in pulse
>   frequency modulation (PFM) mode, transferring energy stored in the
>   input capacitor to the energy storage connected to the BAT pin. The
>   MPPT control loop regulates the VIN voltage at the level sampled at
>   the MPPT pin and stored at the capacitor through the CBP and the AGND
>   pins. To maintain the high efficiency of the regulator across a wide
>   input power range, the **current sense circuitry** employs an internal
>   dither peak current limit to control the inductor current.

[image]

Also,

> The boost regulator and regulated output in hysteresis boost mode in
>   the ADP5091/ADP5092 includes **current-limit protection circuitry** to
>   limit the amount of positive current flowing through the **low-side**
>   **boost switch**